# Android bitmap copy too long

Tags: android, performance, bitmap

I want to get bitmap pixels :

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
int[] pixels = new int[bitmap.getByteCount()]; 
bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
    Log.e(TAG, "!!!! time : "+(stopTime - startTime)/  1000000.0+"ms // size: "+pixels.length+");
```

The problem is the executime time of the getPixels method...
Most of the time is less than 1ms but sometimes 25ms !!

I don't know why and this is really embarrassing.

Comment: you cannot speed it up, what do you need the pixels for?

Comment: I need them for tu use an ARM Neon function that I can't display here. You say I cannot speed it up... but why some bitmap pixel extraction are so randomly long ? (It's always the same bitmap)

Comment: you know, your process is not the only one in the system so....

Comment: Yes but the difference is very important between 1ms and 25ms !

Comment: yes i know, and cannot explain this delay better